# Addons not being used for PRs from forks

Tags: github, travis-ci

We have travis setup to build on Pull Requests (github), but it doesn't seem to use the addons specified in the included `.travis.yml` for forks. This makes the build completely fail, as we need mysql 5.6 for our database structure.

- Repository in question: https://github.com/ppy/osu-web
- Example of this issue occurring: https://travis-ci.org/ppy/osu-web/builds/79042469

Our .travis.yml (specifying `mariadb: 10.0`)

```
language: php
php:
  - hhvm
addons:
  mariadb: 10.0
env:
  - DB_USERNAME=root
before_install:
  - nvm install stable
  - nvm use stable
  - ./bin/db_setup
  - ./build.sh
```

This is specific to forks, and [works correctly](https://travis-ci.org/ppy/osu-web/builds/79252654) for collaborators issuing pull requests in the repository itself.